# C++ AMP Performance issue

Tags: gpgpu, performance-testing, c++-amp

I just started using C++ AMP, (as a way to learn it), and I'm **not** getting the expected results in terms of performance, maybe you can help me.

The problem to solve is very simple,
I have a Vector and a Matrix structure (C++ code, btw I'm a newbie in C++)

```
struct Vector
{
    public : float X, Y, Z;
};

struct Matrix
{
    public : float M11, M12, M13, M14,
                   M21, M22, M23, M24,
                   M31, M32, M33, M34,
                   M41, M42, M43, M44;
};
```

The goal is to multiply the same Matrix over and over by millions of these vectors.
Here goes the code that does the computation:

```
Vector compute(const Matrix matrix, const Vector vector) restrict(amp,cpu)
{
    float tx = vector.X;
    float ty = vector.Y;
    float tz = vector.Z;

    Vector result;

    result.X = (matrix.M11 * tx) + (matrix.M12 * ty) + (matrix.M13 * tz) + matrix.M14;
    result.Y = (matrix.M21 * tx) + (matrix.M22 * ty) + (matrix.M23 * tz) + matrix.M24;
    result.Z = (matrix.M31 * tx) + (matrix.M32 * ty) + (matrix.M33 * tz) + matrix.M34;

    return result;
}
```

Now I can call run this method in the CPU or in the GPU.

CPU:

```
Vector* cpu_compute(const Matrix matrix, const Vector *vectors, const int size)
{
    Vector *result = (Vector*)malloc(size * sizeof(Vector));

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        result[i] = compute(matrix, vectors[i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

GPU:

```
Vector* gpu_compute(const Matrix matrix, const Vector *vectors, const int size)
{
    Vector *result = (Vector*)malloc(size * sizeof(Vector));

    array_view<const Vector, 1> vectors_view(size, vectors);
    array_view<Vector, 1> result_view(size, result);

    accelerator acc = pick_accelerator();

    parallel_for_each(acc.default_view, vectors_view.extent, [=](index<1> idx) restrict(amp)
    {
        result_view[idx] = compute(matrix, vectors_view[idx]);
    });

    return result;
}
```

When running this code with 20.2 million vectors I get the following results:

- CPU (C++): 226ms
- CPU (C#) : 223ms
- GPU      : 339ms

And I have several surprises.
First the C# and C++ code run at almost the same speed.
Second, the GPU is not as fast as I would hope.

I know that you have to pay a penalty in memory transfers, but I didn't think it would be that noticeable for this example.
No matter the amount of data I throw in, the GPU is **always** slower.
That means I'm doing something wrong, otherwise no one would use GPU to play games if they were beaten by a single core cpu.

Question: Is there a way this kind of computation can be more performant on the GPU than in the CPU?

Thanks

FYI:
I'm running Windows 7, (which prevents me from using WARP), with an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 690 and an Intel Core i7 3930k.

Comment: I'm still very surprised that the GPU is so slow. Some dumb questions; Are you compiling in Release mode? What floating point precision model are you using? Did you try my suggestion below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have a bad memory-access-to-computation ratio.

Memory access is expensive (copying from CPU to GPU and back) where as computations on copied memory would be cheap (powerful GPU).

You only do little computations and frequently access new values.

To verify this is the case, you could comment out the computation and see how much the running time (just for copying) is.

Also, if you are starting out, [grab the amp book samples on codeplex](http://ampbook.codeplex.com/), where you also get a good idea of what works in which way.

Comment: That's most likely the issue, 3ms are spent crunching the data.
The rest of the time is spent copying data back and forth.

Answer (score 3):

Right now you are paying the overhead of copying the result data onto the GPU, even though you only ever write to it.

```
array_view<Vector, 1> result_view(size, result);
result_view.discard_data()
```

You should call discard_data() so that this data is not copied.

Even taking this into consideration you are unlikely to see significant speedup here as the amount of work you are doing will not hide the cost of the copies to and from the GPU.

Another side note. You might try writing your C++ version as a loop and seeing if you can get the compiler to automatically vectorize the calculation. This is trivial to do and may give you a significant speedup.

[Auto-Parallelization and Auto-Vectorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872235.aspx)